# How to update two join tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I intend to write a procedure in SqlServer that can update the joined tables,in my case i have two tables (HowzeEducation & HowzeDegree) so i have written the following query but it has errors and does not work properly.Here is my code:

```
declare 
@HowzeEducationId int,
@DegreeId int,
@FieldName nvarchar(50),
@FinishLevelDate date,
@Average decimal(4,2),
@SchoolName nvarchar(50),
@StudyCityDescribtion nvarchar(100),
@ThesisTitle nvarchar(200),
@Describtion nvarchar(600)


update (
  select he.FieldName,
     he.Average,
     he.Describtion,
     he.FinishLevelDate,
     he.SchoolName,
     he.StudyCityDescribtion,
     he.ThesisTitle,
     hd.DegreeId
from HowzeEducation he inner join HowzeDegree hd on 
     he.HowzeEducationId=hd.HowzeEducationId
   )
 set he.FieldName=@FieldName ,
he.Average=@Average,
he.Describtion=@Describtion,
he.FinishLevelDate=@FinishLevelDate,
he.SchoolName=@SchoolName,
he.StudyCityDescribtion=@StudyCityDescribtion,
he.ThesisTitle=@ThesisTitle,
hd.DegreeId=@DegreeId

where he.HowzeEducationId=@HowzeEducationId
```

How can solve this problem?

Comment: Can you care to post the error?

Comment: An `UPDATE` statement (or `INSERT` or `DELETE`) can affect one (1) table only. You'll have to write it as 2 `UPDATE`s.

Comment: Why you don't use transaction to update both tables.

Answer (score 2):

You can't update two table using one update statement, you have to use two updates as below:

```
declare 
@HowzeEducationId int,
@DegreeId int,
@FieldName nvarchar(50),
@FinishLevelDate date,
@Average decimal(4,2),
@SchoolName nvarchar(50),
@StudyCityDescribtion nvarchar(100),
@ThesisTitle nvarchar(200),
@Describtion nvarchar(600)


update HowzeEducation 
set Average=@Average,
    Describtion=@Describtion,
    FinishLevelDate=@FinishLevelDate,
    SchoolName=@SchoolName,
    StudyCityDescribtion=@StudyCityDescribtion,
    ThesisTitle=@ThesisTitle,
    FieldName=@FieldName
where HowzeEducationId=@HowzeEducationId

update HowzeDegree
set   DegreeId=@DegreeId
where HowzeEducationId=@HowzeEducationId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify multiple tables through a view, try something like:

```
create view HowzeView as
select he.FieldName,
     he.Average,
     he.Describtion,
     he.FinishLevelDate,
     he.SchoolName,
     he.StudyCityDescribtion,
     he.ThesisTitle,
     hd.DegreeId
from HowzeEducation he inner join HowzeDegree hd on 
     he.HowzeEducationId=hd.HowzeEducationId

update HowzeView
set FieldName=@FieldName,
Average=@Average,
Describtion=@Describtion,
FinishLevelDate=@FinishLevelDate,
SchoolName=@SchoolName,
StudyCityDescribtion=@StudyCityDescribtion,
ThesisTitle=@ThesisTitle,
DegreeId=@DegreeId
```

Comment: [CREATE VIEW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx), Updatable Views: "You can modify the data of an underlying base table through a view ... Any modifications ... must reference columns from only one base table". So, no.

Comment: Oh, my bad. That just seems like something that should've been supported, at least under some conditions.